# Can QT integrate natively with windows?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt

Can QT integrate with OS code? E.g on Windows I want to add a system tray application. On OS X I want the same application in the top bar. Is there a way that I can implement the os specific code myself and then plugin the qt code to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing about using Qt that would prevent you from also linking in Windows libraries and making Win32 API calls. On Windows, you'll use [this API<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On Mac OS, [this one<sup>[Apple Dev]</sup>](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: first of all, thx for the links. secondly, the shell_notifyicon interface takes a notifyicondata struct which has a hWnd field for passing a handle to the window. Can I get a handle to the window (that Windows will understand) from a qt object?

Comment: I believe `QWidget::winId()` (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winId) should do it.